# Raspberry: serial port not working after boot, application should be restarted

Tags: linux, qt, serialization

I wrote a QT application on Raspberry and I implemented a serial communication between Arduino and raspberry. The serial communication is working well, but I'm facing an issue after boot.
When I launch the application the first time, the serial communication is not working, even if I wait time.. I should end and restart the application, then it will work perfectly.
[image]
This is the code, I'm not doing something special, consider that after then I start to read/write through serial.
Should I do something before start the communication?
Why it could not work fine?

Comment: Please copy-paste code as **text** into the question. Do not use images to convey code!

Comment: Very strange, the only thing I see here is the position of the tcflush() line my idea is that it should be after the tcsetattr.

Comment: Sorry for the image but I'm writing through VNC and copy&paste doesn't work.. I should copy in a file and get the file through usb stick.. you know.. :-P. I was not expecting someone tries.. I was hoping someone faced and fixed the issue. I tried to invert tcflush() but nothing. I added also a 0,5 seconds.. nothing

Comment: I did more tests and not only the serial communication is not starting after boot, all GPIO is not working. But when I call the second time the same application, all works.. could be a question of timing? Should I wait something is ready before use?

Comment: I still having the problem. Nobody can help me?